# Format Dates in Crystal report

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports. I have a report on which there are two date fields : Benefit Start & Benefit End Dates.

I have to compare the age of the employees.

1. If age>65 years, Benefit Start date should be `20160101`.
2. If age<65 years, Benefit Start date should be first day of the month effective.

> eg: if the date is '09/21/2015', the output should be'09/01/2015'.

Similarly for benefit End Date,

If age<65 years, Benefit End date should be last day of the month effective.
eg:  if the date is '09/02/2015', the output should be `09/30/2015`.
How do I hard code the days in dates so that I get the first day & last day of the months for the two fields?

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`date(year({effectivedate})+1,1,1)` -- returns Jan 1 of following year
`date(year({effectivedate}),month({effectivedate}),1)` -- returns first day of month for effective date
`date(year(dateadd('m',1,{effectivedate})),month(dateadd('m',1,{effectivedate})),1)-1` -- returns last day of effective month

I hope... I didnt test

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,will try & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Start date:

```
DateSerial (YEAR(Cdate(datefield)),MONTH(Cdate(datefield)) ,1 );
```

End Date:

```
DateADD("d",-1,DateAdd ("m",1 ,Cdate(datefield) ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,will try & let you know.